# How do I check for the existence of a backone callback?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Let's say I've installed a callback on my backbone model like so:

```
model.on('some_event', () => {
    console.log('it happened.');
})
```

Is there a way to check that this callback is installed? My goal is to avoid installing the callback twice.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14377856/backbone-add-event-listener-only-if-doesnt-already-exist for the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check to see if your model has an event registered with the following:

```
if(model._events && model._events['some_event']) {
    // already registered
}
```

Alternatively, if your goal is just to prevent registering a callback multiple times, you could precede your `on` call with an `off` call:

```
model.off('some_event').on('some_event', () => {
    console.log('it happened.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried calling off first and that did what I wanted. That seems a bit cleaner than inspecting _events.

Comment: @matthewatabet using variables starting with _ are generally considered to be private to the library and library writers may deprecate it with upcoming updates hence I will suggest to go with the second approach.

Comment: @nikhilmehta -- if you read my comment carefully, you'll note i *didn't* use _events. thanks!

Comment: @matthewatabet I mistakenly marked you in the comment I wanted to mark  lucasjackson. Sorry.